# TOAD for ORACLE: SQL Limit gives error 'Expected EOF or FETCH FOR OFFSET'

Tags: sql, toad, sql-limit

```
SELECT a.valor,  
       Cc_obt_nom_titular_cuenta (1, a.valor)    Titular,  
       count('*') cnt
FROM   cc_audit_obj a,  
       cuenta_efectivo b  
WHERE  a.campo = 'NUM_CUENTA'  
       AND Trunc(a.fecha) BETWEEN '01-jun-2021' AND '05-jun-2021'  
       AND b.num_cuenta = a.valor  
       AND b.cod_empresa = '1'  
GROUP BY a.valor, a.usuario
ORDER  BY cnt desc
LIMIT 50
```

The limit tag will give the error stated in title.

I want to limit the records to 50. How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed

Comment: I'd try `FETCH FIRST 50 ROWS ONLY` instead of `LIMIT 50`. The ANSI SQL way!

Comment: FETCH did it! Thank you